# Why is codinghorror.com down for me?

Tags: internet-connection

I get

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to www.codinghorror.com

Ping and tracert give the following output

```
c:\>ping www.codinghorror.com

Pinging codinghorror.com [204.9.177.195] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 204.9.177.195:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

c:\>tracert www.codinghorror.com

Tracing route to codinghorror.com [204.9.177.195]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  7    26 ms    26 ms    27 ms  lag2.ar4.fra4.gblx.net [67.16.145.242]
  8    26 ms    26 ms    26 ms  ae-9-0.edge4.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [4.68.63.241]
  9   174 ms   177 ms   174 ms  vlan80.csw3.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [4.69.154.190]
 10   229 ms   211 ms   224 ms  ae-82-82.ebr2.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [4.69.140.25]
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13   174 ms   174 ms   174 ms  ae-71-71.csw2.NewYork1.Level3.net [4.69.134.70]
 14   174 ms   174 ms   178 ms  ae-72-72.ebr2.NewYork1.Level3.net [4.69.148.37]
 15   176 ms   176 ms   225 ms  4.69.135.185
 16   174 ms   174 ms   174 ms  ae-91-91.csw4.SanJose1.Level3.net [4.69.153.14]
 17   174 ms   198 ms   209 ms  ae-92-92.ebr2.SanJose1.Level3.net [4.69.153.29]
 18   176 ms   176 ms   176 ms  ae-5-5.car1.Oakland1.Level3.net [4.69.134.37]
 19   174 ms   174 ms   174 ms  SIX-APART-L.car1.Oakland1.Level3.net [4.71.200.18]
 20   179 ms   179 ms   179 ms  204.9.176.65
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

At the same time, surfing via an anonimizer works fine.

Comment: maybe the site doesn't repond to ping?

Comment: @TobyAllen it does, I checked.

Comment: Try testing the URL in `chrome://net-internals/#tests`.

Comment: @Dennis Every test fails with `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT (-118)`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your DNS is working fine.

Possible reasons why you may be unable to reach a site directly, but can via a proxy:

- Clear your cookies, maybe the site is reacting improperly to a stale cookie
- You have a web proxy is that inserting something or taking away something that may be causing the remote web server to refuse to reply to you.  But typically this only happens with software that removes "Referrer" headers to prevent hotlinking - I don't think it applies in your case.
- You've been banned from the site and the site's web server is refusing to reply to you.
- You are behind a NAT router and the site administrator has banned your network's public IP.  This may be possible if you are in a campus setting such as a large workplace or university.
- The site has experienced many hacking attempts or other bad behavior originating from your ISP or a large IP range thereof and has banned an entire IP range, including yours.
- Some malware or local proxy on your system is interfering with your page loads.

Comment: That covers almost everything, but you should really include suggestions for testing for the right explanation.

Comment: It's not the cookies, I've checked. Site does not have logins, so it can't be no 2. I doubt that there is malware which solely targets codinghorror :) As for the other things, I am not sure that I can check if my IP (range) has been banned.

Comment: Problem is not resolved, points awarded for most complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to call the Support of your ISP.
It seems to me that they have banned that IP segment.

If you know someone using the same ISP in your area, then you could ask him to test this theorem.

Comment: My ISP banned the site IP segment or vice versa?

Comment: Both are possible, but I would first suspect the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with another site a while back, I fixed it by changing the primary DNS server.
Have you tried changing your DNS server? I would suggest trying Google's DNS [8.8.4.4].

Also check your hosts file, maybe you added the site there by mistake.

Comment: Try reading [answer].

Comment: If it were a DNS problem, ping and tracert would have the same issue.

Comment: Yup, I guess you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT message you got I'd suspect a routing issue somewhere between you and the site.  Try restarting the router - if that doesn't fix it it will probably be back within a few days but it is likely out of your hands.

Comment: I can't restart it, it's managed by someone else.

Comment: It's very likely a route issue then - let the administrator know.

Comment: DNS corruption in the router is a possibility. Check by the model to find if it susceptible to this problem.